# Draw line through 2 view in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, line

How to draw line from view1 to view2 like image.

[image]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw bezier path from one view to another view.

```
   let border = CAShapeLayer()
    border.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    border.lineDashPattern = [6, 4]
    border.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    border.lineCap = kCALineCapSquare
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 10)
    border.strokeColor = Color.blue.cgColor
    border.fillColor = nil
    border.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 10).cgPath
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(border)
```